# unable to SSH into my AWS EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

My security group has the following

```
1. Type
Oracle-RDS
2. Protocol
TCP
3. Port Range
1521
4. Source
Custom - 0.0.0.0/0

1. Type
SSH
2. Protocol
TCP
3. Port Range
22
4. Source
Custom - 0.0.0.0/0
```

I used an AWS Marketplace Virtual Machine (CentOS 7.4 Minimal) and I've associated an Elastic IP to the instance.

I created an SSH Key and downloaded the keys to my computer.

when I try to ssh, i get timed out.

```
ssh centos@34.238.96.7
ssh: connect to host 34.238.96.7 port 22: Connection timed out
```

[image]

[image]

[Link to document that I was following](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15GTD9Wogr4fUg0iPnoKY2S89kbQ_h4-9HxPd2EQ1AVw/edit#)

Comment: Are you still having a problem? Your IP address is answering ssh correctly right now.

Answer (score 0):

First try to stop and start the intance...

second check at you instance security group if your ip is open to use ssh with yor IP at port 22

third force to your your sshkey

ssh -i /location/of/.ssh/key centos@34.238.96.7

Comment: i added some images. My security group shows that port 22 is open to all inbound connections. However I don't get connection refused. It says timed out. No idea whats going on.

Comment: Michael Hampton is right, your server is answering correctly to ssh port... i recive Permission denied  to try access your server... everything its ok... 

try ssh -i /location/of/.ssh/key centos@34.238.96.7

Comment: You may want to do simple ip/port troubleshooting. Try from your machine running:
```telnet $IP $port``` or ```nmap tcp port 22 $IP```

e.g. 
```telnet 34.238.96.7 22 
```

Once done, please provide the output here. Firewall might be blocking your connection on either ends.

Comment: based on the following output there is no problem on the remote side:
```telnet 34.238.96.7 22
Trying 34.238.96.7...
Connected to 34.238.96.7.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4```

to exit telnet "ctrl + ]" then Enter and type  "quit"

Comment: About your instance i recommed to change the type t2.medium to t3a.medium, its cheaper and better performance... to do that you must enable --ena-support at the instance... after that u must change the type, mount the disks and edit  /etc/fstab

:)

Comment: @Tharivol I did a bit of benchmarking t3 vs t3a using Nginx / PHP / MySQL and found the [T3A AMD instances 10% - 30% slower than Intel T3](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/aws-amazon-web-services/benchmark-aws-ec2-a-series-amd-epyc-instances-t3a-m5a-t3-m5-t2/) for my workloads. See blog post for more details. I'm using a t3a.nano as they're a bit cheaper and performance is still fine, and cheaper than t2.

Comment: good to know tim, but i think that difference is between application to application... i use too Nginx / PHP / MySQL, and I noticed a better performance of 10~15%